# Why SaveChanges via Entity Framework affects more records during adding one record via dbContext

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I have service created as follows in ViewModelLocator:

```
 var context = new DbEntities();
 SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPaymentLogService>(() => new PaymentLogService(context));


public PaymentLogService(installmentsEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _paymentLogRepository = new PaymentLogRepository(context);
    }
```

I have repository created as follows:

public PaymentLogRepository(DbEntities context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

When adding row via Entity Framework like this:

```
public int Add(PaymentLog entity)
{
    _context.PaymentLogs.Add(entity);
    var affectedRows = _context.SaveChanges();

    return numberOfAddedItems;
}
```

Above function removes records. `affectedRows = 2`. `PaymentLogs` is referenced to another object and firstly new object is not added and moreover referenced LoanAgreement row is removed from database.

WHY?

New record prepared to be added is conveyed like this:

```
 var result = new PaymentLog() { PayedAmount = newPayment.PaymentAmout, LoanAgreementID = newPayment.LoanID };
```

`PaymentLog` object has a reference to `LoanAgreement`. As seen above, before conveying it to function I only set referenced FK ID. I Expected new record to be added. No record was added. One was removed and saveChangs returned value = 2.

```
CREATE TABLE "PaymentLogs" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,"LoanAgreementID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"PayedAmount" DECIMAL NOT NULL,

 FOREIGN KEY ([LoanAgreementID]) REFERENCES [LoanAgreements] ([ID]) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: There is not enough information posted here to answer that question. Please post something that we can reproduce.

Comment: try to look at this question outside ... i don't understand anything

Comment: `_context` exists before your `Add()` method is called.  If it has other pending changes from before `Add()` was called, they will all get executed when you call `SaveChanges()`.  What are you doing with `_context` ***before*** calling `Add()`?

Comment: Because _context is a field, it can be used in other places. We can't actually fix this problem without code of all methods of this class.

Comment: You keep posting little bits of disconnected code that don't give the full picture.  This won't help.  Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post some helpful code.  Alternatively, add this somewhere in your code to trace the SQL that EF is generating, and if you can't make sense of it, edit your post with the logs: `_context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your remarks "sstan" I added logging context info:

```
_context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

It occured that following update was performed.

```
UPDATE [LoanAgreements] SET [LoanTypeID] = @p0 WHERE ([ID] = @p1);
```

-- @p0: '0' (Type = Int64)
-- @p1: '7' (Type = Int64)

Above update was done unnecessary.

- When user adds new LoanAgreement from WPF UI then in case it succeded I resets UI like this via binding:

  private ProductTypeDto _productType;
  public ProductTypeDto ProductType
  {
      get { return _productType; }
      set
      {
      _productType = value;
      //this caused unwanted updated: 
      _loanAgreement.LoanTypeID = _productType.ID;
      }
  }
- Then every next action tried to perform what was done in above setter;
- It occured this to be bad idea to bind directly to db object which is known to context.
- Maybe another problem is related to _context itself since it is created once and lives all the time.